# Using Backward compatibility scripts to interface old php scripts with new versions

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, backwards-compatibility

I have a website script programmed in PHP v 5.2
Is it okay to use compatibility scripts to run the code on PHP7 without changing the script or downgrading the PHP?

**What are the problems that would arise from such scripts?**

The compatibility script is of the shape:

```
if (!function_exists("session_unregister")) {

    function session_unregister($key) {
        // use the recommended way to unregister session variables
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }

}
```

Also can it be used to recreate mysql functions interface to mysqli functions?
Like:

```
if (!function_exists("mysql_fetch_array")) {

    function mysql_fetch_array(&$result) {
        $ar = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        return $ar;
    }

}
```

Comment: I would think that this approach would be OK as a temporary bridge between your current codebase and updating your codebase to remove deprecated function calls. As a long-term solution it will probably cause confusion during maintenance.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Thanks